# PHP -displaying four items of an associative array with specific key and value in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, associative-array

i'm trying to build a Media Library website using php.
i have 3 categories (books , movies and music ) that i included in the same array like this :

```
    <?php 

$catalog = [];
$catalog[101] = [
    "title" => "Book1",
    "img" => "img/img1.jpg",
    "genre" => "genre1",
    "year" => "2016",
    "category" => "Books",
    "author" => "someone"

];
$catalog[102] = [
    "title" => "Book2",
    "img" => "img/img1.jpg",
    "genre" => "genre1",
    "year" => "2016",
    "category" => "Books",
    "author" => "someone"

];
$catalog[103] = [
    "title" => "Book3",
    "img" => "img/img1.jpg",
    "genre" => "genre1",
    "year" => "2016",
    "category" => "Books",
    "author" => "someone"

];
$catalog[104] = [
    "title" => "Book4",
    "img" => "img/img1.jpg",
    "genre" => "genre1",
    "year" => "2016",
    "category" => "Books",
    "author" => "someone"

];
$catalog[105] = [
    "title" => "Book5",
    "img" => "img/img1.jpg",
    "genre" => "genre1",
    "year" => "2016",
    "category" => "Books",
    "author" => "someone"

];
$catalog[201] = [
    "title" => "Movie1",
    "img" => "img/img2.png",
    "genre" => "genre1",
    "year" => "2016",
    "category" => "Movies",
    "actor" => "someone"

];
$catalog[202] = [
    "title" => "Movie2",
    "img" => "img/img2.png",
    "genre" => "genre1",
    "year" => "2016",
    "category" => "Movies",
    "actor" => "someone"

];
$catalog[203] = [
    "title" => "Movie3",
    "img" => "img/img2.png",
    "genre" => "genre1",
    "year" => "2016",
    "category" => "Movies",
    "actor" => "someone"

];
$catalog[204] = [
    "title" => "Movie4",
    "img" => "img/img2.png",
    "genre" => "genre1",
    "year" => "2016",
    "category" => "Movies",
    "actor" => "someone"

];
$catalog[301] = [
    "title" => "Song1",
    "img" => "img/img3.png",
    "genre" => "genre1",
    "year" => "2016",
    "category" => "Music",
    "singer" => "someone"

];
$catalog[302] = [
    "title" => "Song2",
    "img" => "img/img3.png",
    "genre" => "genre1",
    "year" => "2016",
    "category" => "Music",
    "singer" => "someone"

];
$catalog[303] = [
    "title" => "Song3",
    "img" => "img/img3.png",
    "genre" => "genre1",
    "year" => "2016",
    "category" => "Music",
    "singer" => "someone"

];
$catalog[304] = [
    "title" => "Song4",
    "img" => "img/img3.png",
    "genre" => "genre1",
    "year" => "2016",
    "category" => "Music",
    "singer" => "someone"

];

?>
```

and then i displayed in the home page just the books category

> "category" => "Books",

using this code :

```
<ul class="item">
           <?php 
               foreach($catalog as $id => $tem){
                if ($tem["category"] == "Books"){
                    echo get_item_html($id,$tem);

                    }
                }

            ?>
            </ul>
```

the get_item_html function is this :

```
<?php
function get_item_html($id,$tem){
$output = "<li><a href='#'><img class='img' src='" . $tem["img"] . "' 
alt='" . $tem["title"] . "' />" . "<p>view details</p>" . "</a></li>";

return $output;

}

?>
```

Now all the books items will be displayed in the Home page but i want Just four of them to be displayed randomly.

so what i want is to display 4 items of the array randomly. but they all should have the key and value of : "category" => "Books",.

thank you in advance .

Comment: shall `shuffle($catalog);` works for you before `foreach` loop?

Comment: I think it will shuffle them but still all the items will displayed . i want just four .

Comment: why can't you just stop the loop after 4 iterations?

Comment: im not that experienced in php . im stil learning . how could i do that?

Comment: @ATrihop check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
array_rand(array,number)
```

`array`     Required. Specifies an array

`number`    Optional. Specifies how many random keys to return

It returns an array, if `number` is greater than 1.

You might implement it, like this:

```
function is_book($value){
    return $value["category"] == "Books"
}

$random_books_catalog = array_rand(array_filter( $catalog , "is_book"), 4);
```

Comment: if i do this even the items with the . key => value . : "category" => "Movies", and "category" => "Music", will be displayed.

Comment: You have to use this on `$catalog`, not the individual entries. (First, of course you need to choose your `Book` category, of course). With `array_rand($catalog, 4)` you should get exactly your four arrays which you can individually put in your `get_item_html` function. The `$id` seems to obsolet, btw.

Comment: i dindt downvote your comment someone else did. im still new in here i cant vote commnts.

Comment: @AndreasGnyp, without additional filtering before that, `array_rand($catalog, 4)` will include also array elements with category different than `Books`.

Comment: @midkosoft: Sure, I just added the suggestion to filter it first.

Comment: this will display four random suggestions including movies , books and songs. right?? i did it but now after that i want foor random suggestions that will include just books . i want to sort just items with the key "categorie" and it's value "books" and then display just four of them in my home page.

Comment: aah and how can i choose the book category??. sorry i dont work that much with php so ...

Comment: I had to look up a few things, but I edited my answer and added a peace of code. I haven't tested it, but it should do exactly, what you want.

Comment: @AndreasGnyp Your code worked too thank you so much . can you just please explain the array_filter a little bit so i can reuse it if i need to.

Comment: (And it is much shorter, isn't it? ;-)) Sure: It takes an array and returns an array, with all the items, for which the called function returns `true`. Further reading and capabilities can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_rand.asp

Comment: And this is the page for array_filter: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php ... sorry, had the other one open. :)

Comment: yeah it is much simple . you was so helpful thank youu soo much

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle the array and add a counter:

```
<?php
    $nOfBooks = 4;
    $countBooks = 0;
    shuffle($catalog);
    foreach ($catalog as $id => $tem) {
        if ($tem["category"] == "Books" && $countBooks < $nOfBooks) {
            echo get_item_html($id, $tem);
            $countBooks++;
        } elseif ($countBooks >= $nOfBooks){
            // avoiding unnecessary iterations
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: yeaah it worked  thank youu soo much . but i didnt understand how php knew that the variable $nOfBooks is the number of items. we didnt defined it

Comment: `$nOfBooks` interact with `$countBooks` which we increment only if current array element has category Books. once these two variables become equal, we exit (break) the loop.

Comment: aaah so $nOfBooks = 4 is the number of times the server find and display an item from the books category. so this is how the loop works : it find the first item from the category and display it then search for an other one and display it again ... and $countBooks = 0; is being incremented in every step. and when $countBooks >= $nOfBooks we exit the loop.Thank youuu